# Print words with at least 4 consonants javascripts

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the array ["cat", "dog", "reindeer", "penguin", "crocodile"], print all words with at least 4 consonants.

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Get a paper and a pen and write down your ideas and some pseudo code. Hint : You can loop over a string

Comment: You can count the occurrences of consonants in your string, when the count reach 4 you can return those string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commented code below can help you:

```
const animals = ["cat", "dog", "reindeer", "penguin", "crocodile"]
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

animals.forEach(animal=>{
  let counter=0
  //spliting the word in letters
  animal.split('').forEach(letter=>{
    //checking if the letter is really a letter and if it is not a vowel
    if(letter.toLocaleLowerCase()>='a'&&letter.toLocaleLowerCase()<='z'&&!vowels.some(v=>v===letter.toLocaleLowerCase()))
    counter++
  })
  if(counter>=4)
  console.log(animal)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

With [String `match()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method for pattern-matching, and  [Array.prototype.`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for conditional screening of items, we can write a concise one-liner:

```js
> const animals = ["cat", "dog", "reindeer", "penguin", "crocodile"]

> animals.filter( animal => animal.match(/[^aeiou]/gi).length >= 4)
["reindeer", "penguin", "crocodile"]
```

Do study `regex` as much as possible. Here are few resources: [quick overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXQxhojSdZM), [deatiled demo](https://youtu.be/EkluES9Rvak)